# Undefined when trying to store http response to variable javascript

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, http-get

```
function getUserID(externalEmail) {
        fetch("https:....SOME HOST" + "+'" + externalEmail + "'", {
                method:'GET',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'Some Username field':'<username>',
                        'Some Password field':'<password>'
                    },

        })
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function(json) {
            console.log(json.result[0].id)
            return json.result[0].id
        }).catch(error = > console.log(error));
    }
```

I want to return the id to this function getUserID so i can store it in a variable, something like.

```
var usersID = getUserID()
```

I keep getting undefined, i can only see the ID when i console.log().
PS. i specify the userEmail before the function getUserID

If anyone can help that will be much appreciated.

My latest Change....

```
function delay(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var email = "@email.com"
    setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(fetch("https:....SOME HOST" + "+'" + externalEmail + "'", {
                method:'GET',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'Some Username field':'<username>',
                        'Some Password field':'<password>'
                    },

              }))
             } ,1000);
   });
}
delay()
      .then(function(response){
          return response.json()
      }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: read on async/await. You cannot directly assign the return of getUserID() since it is asynchronous. You want to hold the assignment until the promise resolves to a value. You can do that by using the keyword "await".

Comment: Try returning the fetch inside `getUserID`. It can then be awaited or the value can be used inside a `then`.

Comment: You forgot return before fetch

Comment: @DhananjaiPai thank you for your comment, can you provide a small example for me please, i read about async and added async before the function, but reach a problem i have seen that i am not sure how to solve,"promise {undefined}"

Comment: thank you @evolutionxbox when i add return i now see promise { <pending> } which i have also seen but am confused on how to solve this.

Comment: thank you @AluanHaddad my previous comment is also for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad Just had a look at that, thank you, I will try to use a promise and understand how it works

Comment: @DhananjaiPai i have changed my code and now it is pending, do you know much about this. I will add my code now

Comment: You simply cannot take a promise and use that object as anything meaningful. You must use the result in the `then` function, or use the `await` keyword (for those environments with global await facility) Read the answer(s) to the question posted by @AluanHaddad closely.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, once i re-read that post, is storing a specific variable from the result, lets say result is result[name: "James", id: "123"] will i be able to return the id to the function ```getUserID``` and store it into a global variable through the use of ```then```